# Why does the Nusselt Number for a Constant Surface Temperature, Thermally Fully Developed Circular Pipe Converge To a Constant of 3.66?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, flow

I have flow in a pipe with a constant surface temperature boundary condition. The velocity profile is fully developed and the temperature profile is also fully developed. In my textbook, it says that the Nusselt number stays at a constant 3.66 value when these conditions exist.
I know that the Nusselt number is dependent on the derivative of the temperature in the radial direction at the pipe wall and the mean temperature of the fluid.
The further the fluid travels up the pipe,  the derivative decreases and the mean temperature increases. 
Shouldn't the derivative converge to zero because  the temperature of the fluid eventually reaches the wall temperature? Therefore, shouldn't the Nusselt number keep decreasing past 3.66 and eventually to 0?
If so, then what does thermally developed mean if the temperature is still changing?

Answer (score 2):

The Nusselt number in generally defined as

$$Nu = \frac{hL}{k}$$

In this case $L=D$ and k is constant.  What you're looking for is the heat transfer coefficient $h$. This guy basically captures the effectiveness of the convective process at play.  From it you get a heat flux proportional to the temperature difference between the solid and the bulk flow.

$$q'' = h(T_f -T_s)$$

So your sense of things is right for the pipe flow situation.  The fluid will continually approach the temperature of the pipe and the heat flux will drop as a result, but h will not change.

If you're following certain texts on the subject (e.g. Incropera and DeWitt) you'll see them using temperature to determine $h$.  This special case for laminar pipe flow happens to admit a relatively easy solution.  This general solution, along with the definition of $T_m$, can be expressed as a value of $h$ or $Nu$. Although temperature is used in the calculation, the numerical values of $T$ don't actually change the resulting $Nu$.

Comment: I've written a program to calculate the Nusselt number at each "march" through the pipe. From what the incropera book is telling me, Nu should start at infinity and decrease as the flow goes through the pipe. Then, when the temperature profile is fully developed, Nu should equal 3.66. This happens in my program but it passes 3.66 and keeps decreasing. So a better question is: Does the Nusselt number keep decreasing past 3.66 once it's thermally fully developed? Or should it stay at 3.66 all the time?. Intuitively, I don't think it should stay the same.

Comment: What sort of program did you write? Conceptually, once everything is fully developed the flow pattern is constant, so that aspect of $h$ will be constant.  All that leaves is the temperature distribution to think about. For $h$ to go to zero as we move along the pipe, the flux to the wall $q''$ would have to fall off faster than the temperature difference ($T_s$-$T_m$).  Note that eq. 8.54 is scaled by that difference, thus $T$ and the gradients of $T$ (responsible for conductive heat flow) will also be scaled by the difference. So $q'' \propto \Delta T$ which means $h=constant$

Comment: The program is based on the dimensionless thermal energy equation without diffusion. It's a parabolized energy equation solved by marching. It assumes a fully developed velocity profile is already present. The equation is discretized and solved using a tridiagonal solver. The inputs are Peclet number, x step size, number of radial nodes and pipe length in number of diameters. Then it outputs a temperature profile along the pipe plus the nusselt number at each x value along the pipe.

Comment: Nu depends on Tm but also on the temperature difference at the wall. The dimensionless equation for Nu that I have is:
Nu=(2/1-thetamean)*(dtheta/dr)
So as thetamean increases along the pipe, the value tends to get bigger. But at the same time, the gradient at the wall tends to decrease. So which one wins out? With my results it seems like the gradient has a stronger influence.

Comment: Where did you get that equation for Nu?  It doesn't look dimensionless. 
$Nu$ shouldn't have a direct dependence on $T$, in fact since this formulation ignores buoyancy and uses constant thermal conductivity there is no reason for $Nu$ change in response temperature at all.

Comment: I derived it by equating newtons law of cooling with fouriers conductive heat transfer equation:
 h(Twall-Tmean)=k(dT/dr).

I made it dimensionless and Nu came out of that because Nu=hD/K. 
The thermal conductivity actually does change according to the first equation.

Comment: Ah, the $k(dT/dr)$ terms apply to the solid domain, not the fluid. $h$ captures the combined effects of conduction and convection in the fluid.
Check the derivation in Incropera (sorry they skip solving the equation).  Heat transfer in the fluid is determined by the flow (constant) conductivity (constant) and the magnitude of the $\Delta T$.  The $T(r)$ that satisfies the equation will always be the same shape scaled by a constant related to $D$, $k$ and the $\Delta T$.  For a given $D$ and $k$, $q''$  will always be proportional to $\Delta T$. That's the same as saying that $h$ is constant.

Comment: But what about the definition of Nu=hL/of? This transfer happens at the differential distance between the wall and the fluid where u Is 0. Therefore, the fluid conducts heat. This heat must be the same as what is convected from twall to tmean. So what is wrong with that statement and definition of Nu?

Comment: Sorry I meanth nu=hl/kf

Comment: Yeah, this is where $h$ gets a little tricky conceptually. It wraps in both convection and conduction from the bulk flow to the surface. $h$ mostly is a way of relating some easily measurable temperature (mean or far from the wall) to the heat flux for a given temperature.  You normally don't actually solve the governing equations to find it. It's not about the differential transport, it's about the bulk flow.